# Mysql command not working in termial

Tags: mysql

Can some one exaplain how this:

```
mysqldump mysql -uxxxx -pxxxx testDB TestDBTwo| gzip > "MainWordPress.gz"
```

is looking for tables? I want it to dump both those tables to a single sql file thats gziped.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Its looking for the table testDB ... TestDB is a database not a table ...

Comment: Why not explicitly mention `--databases TestDB TestDBTwo`. And what is  `mysql` immediately after `mysqldump`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to clear some things up:

1. what is the `mysql` mentioned in the command
2. what database are you trying to dump from?
3. what tables are you trying to dump?

Assuming that the `mysql` is actually the database name and `testDB` and `TestDBTwo` are the tables, the correct format of the `mysqldump` command is:

```
mysqldump -uxxx -pyyy --databases mysql testDB TestDBTwo
```

After that you can pipe it where you want to zip it

Check the documentation for mysqldump  [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-backup-excerpt/5.6/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html) at the MySQL site